# using PHP filter_var_array(), why does the FILTER_CALLBACK cast the function argument to a string?

Tags: php, filter, callback, arguments

In the following code, why does the callback function cast the $value argument as string?

```
$post_values = $_POST['dates'];
/*
var_dump of $post_values
array(1) { [0]=> array(3) { ["date"]=> string(10) "2016-05-10" ["starttime"]=> string(5) "12:30" ["endtime"]=> string(5) "14:33" } }
*/



$args = [
  'dates' => [
    'filter' => FILTER_CALLBACK,
    'options' => function ($value) {
      // The $value here has been cast to string. Why?
      // $value now has value of: string(10) "2016-05-10".
      // I expect it to be an array.
      return $value;
    }
  ]
];


$filtered_values = filter_var_array($post_values, $args);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is normal behavior of [`filter_var()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php) and [`filter_var_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var-array.php) functions. Official documentation of [`filter_var()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php) `variable` parameter contains explanation:

> Note that scalar values are converted to string internally before they are filtered.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve the desired result it seems I am using filter_var_array() incorrectly. filter_var_array() will loop through each array element which is the reason the $value is cast to string.